# Word Resizing Pictures when Printed

Tags: windows-10

When I take an Acrobat Snapshot and paste it into a Word document, the inserted picture is properly sized on the screen and in the Preview, but when I print the document the picture is resized smaller.  How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What version of Word are you using? What method are you using to insert the image into Word? What is the images actual size?